# How to debug windows service in vs 2005?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created windows service by using C#.net.I want to debug it.So I selected debug->Attach to process-> checked both checkbox(all user and all session) and selected process and clicked on attach button.But gives Message "Unable to attach.Access denied."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run VS as administrator.